# Cannot convert type 'Void' to 'String' in coercion in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, braintree, braintree-sandbox, braintree-data

So i'm using some libraries and one of the methods, has supposedly return value

> ```
> let data2 = dataCollector.collectCardFraudData({ ( str:String) in })
> ```

But the problem is that the return value is of void type but i could see the value present in it, i've checked a lot of tutorials where they have suggested to change the return type, but since this being a library i don't think i can do that.Is there any other way to get that value converted to string ??

I'm also kinda new Swift, so please any inputs would be helpfull

Thanks

Comment: Please add the declaration line of `collectCardFraudData`

Comment: - (void)collectCardFraudData:(void (^)(NSString *deviceData))completion;

Comment: not sure if this helps

Comment: @Sam collectCardFraudData not a return any value. this is a compilation block.if get a string inside a block

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The function has no return value. The Swift equivalent is

```
func collectCardFraudData(completion: @escaping (String) -> Void)
```

So you have to call it with the syntax below. `deviceData` is passed as a parameter and you have to call `completion` when you're done.

```
dataCollector.collectCardFraudData { deviceData in 

  // do something with deviceData
  completion()
}
```

Answer (score -1):

I don't know much. Just the guess. Your function is returning the value via completion handler. You should use it like this

```
let data2 = dataCollector.collectCardFraudData({ str in
    print(str) // str available here
})
```

Answer (score -1):

As collectCardFraudData has a closure where it give you 'str' value inside that block direct assigning it to 'data2' is causing you error.

Try below code and please let me know if it works

```
var data2 = String()
dataCollector.collectCardFraudData({ str in 
    data2 = "\(str)"
})
```

Thank you

Comment: 1. `collectCardFraudData` may be async function, and this code won't work; 2. `"\(str)"` — why? `str` is already a `String`, why do you need to interpolate it into `String`?